# Rerouting all the traffic to another server

Tags: apache, redirect, server, proxy

I have a server with open ports 80, 443 and 6789 (websocket). This server is called M.

I have another server called S which is between the users and server M. The role of server S is to act as a proxy so that users do not interact with the server M directly. How can I make the above setup? I tried rerouting traffic using iptables, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) if you want to implement this using Apache.

For other alternatives look for application-level proxies (or gateways), not so much at the network-layer (like what you tried to do using iptables).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).